# Compute zoom level based on screen density

Tags: bing-maps

I'm experiencing with bing maps in a Xamarin.Forms application targeting Android and iOS.
The same code on 2 devices with different screen size and density shows a very different result:

Android (Moto E4 Plus) 1280 x 720 px / 267 ppp

[image: The map on Android]

iOS (iPhone 7 Plus) 1920 x 1080 / 401 ppi

[image: the map on iOS]

So I'm thinking that I simply need to compute the appropriate zoom level to use when calling [map.setView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/map/change-the-map-view)({center: ..., zoom: ... }).

Am I on the right track here? If so how can I compute the zoom level based on the screen density?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are methods available on the map control to automatically calculate the appropriate view given a collection of items. Can you clarify exactly what map control you're hosting in Xamarin, and what API you're calling to set the view?

Comment: I may have found a solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/fa924dad-fab4-46ad-b5d6-cecdeb9721c7/bing-map-control-v8-returns-wrong-values-after-resize?forum=bingmapsajax). I'll confirm in a few days.

Comment: That solution applies to the HTML map control. Are you hosting the HTML control in a web view? If so, that should work. You may want to take a look at the native SDK available for Android/iOS as it may perform better than an HTML solution. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/sdk-native

Comment: This was a combination of the map control not being able to detect the div size change (see my comment above) and the fact that the LocationRect width and height should be divided by the device screen density to show the exact same portion of the map.